# Why does setting a Series dtype raise a TypeError when the dtype is (apparently) what would be chosen anyway?

Tags: python, pandas

This series...

```
pd.Series([pd.Timestamp.utcnow() for v in range(5)])

0   2018-05-16 08:24:29.673274+00:00
1   2018-05-16 08:24:29.673274+00:00
2   2018-05-16 08:24:29.673274+00:00
3   2018-05-16 08:24:29.673274+00:00
4   2018-05-16 08:24:29.673274+00:00
dtype: datetime64[ns, UTC]
```

...can be seen to have dtype = datetime64[ns, UTC].

But setting it explicitly raises a TypeError.

```
pd.Series([pd.Timestamp.utcnow() for v in range(5)], dtype='datetime64[ns, UTC]')
TypeError: data type not understood
```

Even setting it to the explicit value from an identical series does the same...

```
pd.Series([pd.Timestamp.utcnow() for v in range(5)],
          dtype=pd.Series([pd.Timestamp.utcnow() for v in range(5)]).dtype)
TypeError: data type not understood
```

It seems odd to reject a dtype that would be selected automatically.

Comment: You are confusing a `dtype` with a string representing it. Only certain strings are acceptable, and it is usually better to pass a `dtype` explicitly.

Comment: In this case, a possible dtype is: 
dtype='datetime64[ns]'. UTC time is the default timezone used in pandas.

Comment: Do you have a use case for setting explicitly rather than using `pd.to_datetime` ?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga. I wasn't sure if it would take an object directly so as you can see I tried it both ways, as a string and as an explicit object.  In both cases the resulting error (and stacktrace) is the same.  I believe the string form is being understood partially since mis-spelling 'datetime' vs. missing the space between 'ns' and 'UTC' result in different errors.

Comment: @jpp I had a case, I since worked around it but I feel this is a bug.

Comment: @Dvg25 I deal with many times and prefer to have explicit timezones.  For one thing pandas can't subtract timezone and non-timezone aware series from one another.

Comment: This is *not* a bug. Firstly, you seem to be confused. In both cases you are passing a *string*. In the second, you wrapped it with `str`. i.e. `dtype=str(pd.Series...)`. As an aside, *strings are objects*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - Good spot, have corrected (and tried).  Same error.  Why do you feel it's not a bug, or rather expected behavior?

Comment: Indeed, this *is strange*. It doesn't fail when I pass an empty list as a data-argument...